# ng2-table: Can't bind to 'X' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular

I'm having problems trying to get the demo to work.

1. I've installed the module via:
   `npm i ng2-table --save`
2. I've added the entries in systemjs.config.js for the map and package fields:

> var map = {
>       ...,
>       'ng2-table':                    'node_modules/ng2-table'   };
>
> var packages = {    ...,
>       'ng2-table':                    { defaultExtension: 'js' }   };

3. Copied the html and ts from here: http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

When loading the created component I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'totalItems' since it isn't a known native property

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's because the directives aren't correctly specified in the `directives` attributes of the component where you want to use ng2-table.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-demo',
  template: template,
  directives: [NG_TABLE_DIRECTIVES, PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES] // <------
})
export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  (...)
}
```

Are you sure that `NG_TABLE_DIRECTIVES` is correctly set and / or imported?

Comment: Ah you're right. I only used the NG_TABLE_DIRECTIVES but apparently that wasn't enough.